# How do I store Outlook email search results into an IEnumerable object (C#)

Tags: c#, outlook, ienumerable

How do I store/cast all the (Outlook.Items.Find) results from the following into an IEnumerable object? *Outlook 16.0

```
Outlook.MailItem emailResults = null;
emailResults = mailItems.Find($"[Categories] = 'Important'");
```

I'm trying the following with no success.

```
application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("mapi");
inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
mailItems = inbox.Items;
IEnumerable<Outlook.MailItem> emailResults = null;

emailResults = (IEnumerable<Outlook.MailItem>)mailItems.Find($"[Categories] = 'Important'");
```

I'm trying to be fancy and NOT iterate through each result. Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "no success". What's not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Indeed. I was getting the following "System.InvalidCastException was unhandled.
"

Comment: in the future, please include any error details like that directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Items.Restrict` - it returns enumerable `Items` collection.

Comment: TY sir for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dmitry Streblechenko for the quick answer! Here is my code with the solution.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace oMailBoard
{
    public static class GetMail
    {
        public static void SearchOutLook()
        {
            Outlook.Application application = null;
            Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = null;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = null;
            Outlook.Items mailItems = null;
            IEnumerable<Outlook.MailItem> emails = null;

            string filter = "";
            filter = $"[Categories] = 'Important'"; //Exact match
            filter = $"@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like '%database%'"; //Like match

            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("Outlook").Count() > 0) //Is Outlook Open?
            {
                application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
                nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("mapi");
                inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                mailItems = inbox.Items;

                //Store results into a numerable varible.
                emails = mailItems.Restrict(filter).Cast<Outlook.MailItem>(); 

                //Now I can iterate though the results. 
                foreach (Outlook.MailItem e in emails)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("\f");                  
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Subject);                     
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(emails.Count());

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inbox);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nameSpace);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
                inbox = null;
                nameSpace = null;
                application = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Outlook Not Open!");
            }    
        }        
    }
}
```